# How to find a restaurant that is open now in South Korea in English?

Tags: food-and-drink, south-korea, seoul, opening-hours

I want to eat something in Seoul, South Korea, at midnight (mostly 23:00 to 6:00). In other cities of other countries, you can use Yelp to find a list of restaurants that are open right now, or at least search by "restaurant" at Google Map to check whether a restaurant is open now one by one by tapping on the pin.

However, in South Korea there is no Yelp available. While there are similar restaurant review apps available (reviewsee, etc), most of them are available only in Korean. MangoPlato is available in English but its functionality is limited and you cannot search for restaurants by filtering by "open now".

Also Google Map doesn't work so much as Korean uses Naver Map which is also available mostly in Korean only.

So how can you find a list of restaurants, cafes, or other food shops open now in Seoul, South Korea, in English?

Comment: Didn't try Foursquare? Afaik it only displays currently open results, or at least prioritizes them.

Comment: My 2 cents : use Naver Map with chrome auto-translation

Answer (score 1):

Use [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/). Their website has an 'open now' feature and their mobile app also lets you filter results based on when the restaurant in question is open:

[image]